# Swift function not working inside another function

Tags: swift, function

I'm new on this site but I've been struggling for several days about this issue I found. I wrote this code in order to solve a challenge of the site Codewars; the challenge consists in calculate the mean and the variance from some data about some fictional rainfalls (I attach the complete page on the bottom). In order to end this challenge I created a function to convert the data from this useless string into an array of Doubles. The weird thing is that the function if called outside the main one works properly but inside returns an empty array. I have no idea why is happening this. Thank you very much for every effort you'll put trying to explain me this.

[This is the first part of the Codewars page that explain the callenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfxAt.png)

[This is the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/)

```
//
//  main.swift
//  Prova
//
//  Created by Lorenzo Santini on 13/06/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Lorenzo Santini. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation


func mean(_ d: String,_ town: String) -> Double {
    let arrayOfValues = obtainArrayOfMeasures(d, town)
    var sum: Double = 0
    for element in arrayOfValues {
        sum += element
    }

    return sum / Double(arrayOfValues.count)
}


func variance(_ d: String,_ town: String) -> Double {
    let meanValue: Double = mean(d, town)

    //Here is the problem: when this function is called instead of returning the array containg all the measures for the selected city it returns an empty array
    var arrayOfValues = obtainArrayOfMeasures(d, town)
    var sum: Double = 0
    for element in arrayOfValues {
        sum += pow((element - meanValue), 2)
    }
    return sum / Double(arrayOfValues.count)
}

func isInt(_ char: Character) -> Bool {
    switch char {
    case "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9":
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}

func obtainArrayOfMeasures(_ d: String,_ town: String) -> [Double]{
    //The first array stores the Data string divided for city
    var arrayOfString: [String] = []
    //The second array stores the measures of rainfall of the town passed as argument for the function
    var arrayOfMeasures: [Double] = []

    //Split the d variable containg the data string in separated strings for each town and add it to the arrayOfString array
    repeat {
        let finalIndex = (data.index(of:"\n")) ?? data.endIndex
        arrayOfString.append(String(data[data.startIndex..<finalIndex]))
        let finalIndexToRemove = (data.endIndex == finalIndex) ? finalIndex : data.index(finalIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        data.removeSubrange(data.startIndex..<finalIndexToRemove)
    } while data.count != 0

    //Find the string of the town passed as argument
    var stringContainingTown: String? = nil
    for string in arrayOfString {
        if string.contains(town) {stringContainingTown = string; print("true")}
    }

    if stringContainingTown != nil {
        var stringNumber = ""
        var index = 0

        //Add to arrayOfMeasures the measures of the selected town
        for char in stringContainingTown! {
            index += 1
            if isInt(char) || char == "." {
                stringNumber += String(char)
                print(stringNumber)
            }
            if char == "," || index == stringContainingTown!.count {
                arrayOfMeasures.append((stringNumber as NSString).doubleValue)
                stringNumber = ""
            }
        }
    }

    return arrayOfMeasures
}




var data =  "Rome:Jan 81.2,Feb 63.2,Mar 70.3,Apr 55.7,May 53.0,Jun 36.4,Jul 17.5,Aug 27.5,Sep 60.9,Oct 117.7,Nov 111.0,Dec 97.9" + "\n" +
        "London:Jan 48.0,Feb 38.9,Mar 39.9,Apr 42.2,May 47.3,Jun 52.1,Jul 59.5,Aug 57.2,Sep 55.4,Oct 62.0,Nov 59.0,Dec 52.9" + "\n" +
        "Paris:Jan 182.3,Feb 120.6,Mar 158.1,Apr 204.9,May 323.1,Jun 300.5,Jul 236.8,Aug 192.9,Sep 66.3,Oct 63.3,Nov 83.2,Dec 154.7" + "\n" +
        "NY:Jan 108.7,Feb 101.8,Mar 131.9,Apr 93.5,May 98.8,Jun 93.6,Jul 102.2,Aug 131.8,Sep 92.0,Oct 82.3,Nov 107.8,Dec 94.2" + "\n" +
        "Vancouver:Jan 145.7,Feb 121.4,Mar 102.3,Apr 69.2,May 55.8,Jun 47.1,Jul 31.3,Aug 37.0,Sep 59.6,Oct 116.3,Nov 154.6,Dec 171.5" + "\n" +
        "Sydney:Jan 103.4,Feb 111.0,Mar 131.3,Apr 129.7,May 123.0,Jun 129.2,Jul 102.8,Aug 80.3,Sep 69.3,Oct 82.6,Nov 81.4,Dec 78.2" + "\n" +
        "Bangkok:Jan 10.6,Feb 28.2,Mar 30.7,Apr 71.8,May 189.4,Jun 151.7,Jul 158.2,Aug 187.0,Sep 319.9,Oct 230.8,Nov 57.3,Dec 9.4" + "\n" +
        "Tokyo:Jan 49.9,Feb 71.5,Mar 106.4,Apr 129.2,May 144.0,Jun 176.0,Jul 135.6,Aug 148.5,Sep 216.4,Oct 194.1,Nov 95.6,Dec 54.4" + "\n" +
        "Beijing:Jan 3.9,Feb 4.7,Mar 8.2,Apr 18.4,May 33.0,Jun 78.1,Jul 224.3,Aug 170.0,Sep 58.4,Oct 18.0,Nov 9.3,Dec 2.7" + "\n" +
"Lima:Jan 1.2,Feb 0.9,Mar 0.7,Apr 0.4,May 0.6,Jun 1.8,Jul 4.4,Aug 3.1,Sep 3.3,Oct 1.7,Nov 0.5,Dec 0.7"


var prova = variance(data, "London")
```

Comment: Your second link does not work. It would be even better to post the challenge description as *text,* not as links to screenshots. Links can rot, and text is better readable and searchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `func obtainArrayOfMeasures` modifies the global `data`
variable. When called the second time, `data` is an empty string.

An indicator for this problem is also that making the global data variable *constant*

```
let data =  "Rome:..."
```

causes a compiler error at

```
data.removeSubrange(data.startIndex..<finalIndexToRemove)
// Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'data' is a 'let' constant
```

An immediate fix would be to operate on a *local* mutable copy:

```
func obtainArrayOfMeasures(_ d: String,_ town: String) -> [Double]{
    var data = d

    // ...
}
```

Note however that the function can be simplified to

```
func obtainArrayOfMeasures(_ d: String,_ town: String) -> [Double] {
    let lines = d.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

    guard let line = lines.first(where: { $0.hasPrefix(town)}) else {
        return [] // No matching line found.
    }
    let entries = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
    let numbers = entries.compactMap { Double($0.filter {".0123456789".contains($0) })}
    return numbers
}
```

without mutating any values. You might also consider to return `nil`
or abort with `fatalError()` if no matching entry is found.

Comment: possibly `where line.hasPrefix(town)`

Comment: Or `if let line = lines.first(where: { $0.hasPrefix(town)} )`

Comment: Yes, I would use that with a `guard` though.

Comment: @LorenzoSantini: You are welcome. – This nicely demonstrates how using *constants* can help to avoid errors.

Comment: @LorenzoSantini: Now look up "reduce" and simplify your mean and variance function 

Comment: @MartinR yeah i’ll try to figure out how improve this